# Querying Firebase is becoming painful day by day Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, querying

Working with Firebase from past 3 months made my data "fan-out" and managing redundant data day by day I am feeling as if I am over coding now.

I am typically making logging app. Logging Hours minutes. Here what it does.

- Every user signup trough Google authentication.Data is saved in "/users/[users]"
- Then they further create some Helper or workers  who's time is been logged.
- Workers are saved as "/workers/userID/[workers]
- Logs : A worker is selected and his logs are added in two places
- /logs/userId/[logs] (this is for calculating monthly stats)
- /workder_logs/workerId/[logs] (this is for calculating per worker based stats)

This works fine for me..
But now I am taking this app from productivity app to collaborative app.
Where users can connect with each other and **request or approve logs**

Logs added by one users is reviewed and approved/rejected by other user.
This is what happens when a log in this new logic

- User select a worker again which is now linked to a userid (typically linkedUser field in Worker class)
- Log is added to /logs/userid/
- Log is added to /worker_logs/workderid/
- Log is added to /logs/otherUserId/
- And once he approve it is added to /worker_log/otherUserWorker/
  But before that I need a notification screen. This is where I am getting frustrated by firebase after so many days of work(I am also working on some other project with Firebase).

I want to query this for a single recyclerview.

> Select logs from /logs/myUserid/ where logs.date is between 1dec16 to
>   31dec16 and {  (logs.createdby="not me" and logs.status=unapproved) or
>   (logs.createdby="me" and logs.status=rejected) }

Point is I do not want to maintain further logs redundancies(putting in different buckets namely /log/approved etc and manage them). I am not getting any breakthrough when it comes to querying data in Firebase.
I also feel documentation is not so much helpful.

Comment: "Point is I do not want to maintain further logs redundancies" sounds like you have your answer there. For firebase to be quick you sometimes have to duplicate data to make it easier to query.